# cmake cannot set path variable to previous directory

Tags: cmake

I am trying to set the environment variable path in `cmake` by first getting the directory, then setting the variable:

```
message(STATUS "Setting PICO_SDK_PATH...")
get_filename_component(PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../pico-sdk" ABSOLUTE)
message(STATUS "PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY is set at: ${PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY}")
set({PICO_SDK_PATH} "${PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY}")
message(STATUS "PICO_SDK_PATH is set at: ${PICO_SDK_PATH}")
```

The output shows that I get the correct `PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY`

```
-- Setting PICO_SDK_PATH...
-- PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY is set at: /mnt/c/repos/RP2040/pico-sdk
-- PICO_SDK_PATH is set at:
```

Looks like `PICO_SDK_PATH` is not set properly. Does anyone know what issue I am encountering?

Comment: Is that a typo `set({PICO_SDK_PATH}...)`? To set a variable you need to omit the curly braces.

Comment: @vre you're correct. it is a typo.

Comment: Btw: You're not setting a **environment** variable here, but a cmake variable. setting the environment variable for the process running the cmake configuration can be done via `set(ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH} "${PICO_SDK_DIRECTORY}")`, but you need to use `$ENV{PICO_SDK_PATH}` to get the value, if you want to do this from the cmake script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turn @vre's comment into an answer: Do not use curly braces to set CMake variables, see the [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html).